# How to find out the right String syntax for my bash?

Tags: bashrc

I am getting an error message for this alias:

```
alias ejectall='osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)''
```

And here is the error message:

```
-bash: .bashrc: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: .bashrc: line 15: `alias ejectall='osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)'''
```

I got many aliases there, but i cannot understand this message! **I found many websites with lots of different suggestions of the syntax of the String.**

*I am on OS X Mavericks (10.9.3).*

My question is:

> How to find out my bash version, and depending on that, the right syntax for my bash files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bash --version

alias ejectall=$'osascript -e \'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)'\'
```

Comment: why this "wired" syntax? another alias looks like this: alias systail='tail -f /var/log/system.log'  -- so why is this different??

Comment: Ah yeas, I forgot bash's $' strings. A third option.

Comment: @nextrufus It is not necessary to use this one. I consider it the most simple one but that may be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your quoting—and it's irrelevant which version of bash you have (though you could run `bash --version` or `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` to find out). Those quoting rules haven't changed.

`'`-quotes are simple. They just quote until the next `'`. So in your example:

```
alias ejectall='osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)''
               ^             ^ 
            start           end
```

In other words, starting with "tell application" isn't quoted, to the shell.

You could do:

```
alias ejectall='osascript -e '\''tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)'\'
```

Basically, that ends the quoted string, puts in a single quote (with `\'`), then starts a new quoted string. The adjacent quoted strings get merged together since there isn't a space. You can see:

```
$ echo 'I'\''ll work'
I'll work
```

Your other option is to use `"`-quotes, then you need to escape other other double-quotes with `\"` and also escape dollar signs with `\$`.

```
$ echo "That \"is\" \$3.00."
That "is" $3.00.
```

Or, as Hauke Laging points out in his answer, you can use Bash's `$'`-strings. Those enable various escape sequences inside a '' string, including `\'`.

All of this is detailed under in the "Quoting" section in the bash manpage.

Comment: hm, who should i give my correctness? ;) Thanks a lot! I don't know why there are so many websites with "false" versions of this... i copied many examples, changed them, all wrong....